# Windows 7 computer won't boot, won't restore

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod, windows-7-restore

I installed a printer driver today which required a reboot. After the reboot, my computer blue screened. Windows can't fix the problem itself, and I attempted to do a system restore but it won't take because it says there is a file it can't access (possibly due to AV software).

I can't actually get into Windows to turn off any software, etc, so right now I'm stuck.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the error code of your blue screen? Every BSOD has a different cause.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try with `Last Known Good Configuration`
Last Known Good Configuration, or LKGC for short, is a way in which you can start Windows 7 or XP if you're having trouble starting it normally. Last Known Good Configuration loads the drivers and registry data that worked the last time you successfully started and then shut down Windows 7.
To start Windows 7 using Last Known Good Configuration, press the `F8` key just as, or just before, the Windows 7 splash screen starts to load. This will load the Advanced Boot Options menu.

Comment: no luck with that...it still blue screened.

Comment: @jlbruno :what about the safe-mode? if it's not work use the windows live and delete your printer drivers, if it's not work again test the 'bootrec' in System Recovery Options !

Comment: I couldn't get into safe mode...it blue screened!

Answer (score 0):

boot from  Windows 7 install CD

boot into the command console under Repair and/or Advance options

chkdsk /r c:

reboot and see what happens.

Comment: Is this still relevant if it's a solid state drive?